# Number of combinations-Portfolio Construction

Tags: statistics

Suppose you’re assigned to build portfolios of 6 stocks given the following constraints-
a)  It must have 1 & only 1 Tech. stock
b)  It must have 1 & only 1 mining stock
c)  It must have 2 & only 2 airlines stocks
d)  It must have 3 & only 3 utility stocks
Further…….
i)  There are 4 Tech. stocks to choose from.
ii) There are 5 mining stocks to choose from.
iii)    There are 6 airline stocks to choose from.
iv) There are 8 utility stocks to choose from.

The question is how many unique portfolios can be constructed? Or better yet what is the formula for solving such a problem given the constraints? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is equal to the product of the ways to choose each individual category.

There are $4$ ways to choose Tech and $5$ ways to choose mining.

How many ways are there to choose $2$ airline stocks from $6$? It is $\binom{6}{2}=\frac{6!}{2!(6-2)!}=15$.

Finally there are $\binom{8}{3}=\frac{8!}{3!(8-3)!}=56$ ways to choose the $3$ utility stocks.

So in total there are $4\cdot5\cdot15\cdot56=16800$ ways to select the portfolio.

Comment: Thanks dREaM...I got the same answer but talked myself out of it. I appreciate the help.